# Min Max range JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, math

Please, could anyone explain to me why we need to define a min and a max range using the code(or formula) below?

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min
```

More explicitly, why substracting min + 1 from max to add min after the parenthisis.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Math.random()` gives you a number between 0 and 1. And if you want an integer between to larger values, you have to multiply it by the range and then add the minimum value.

Comment: ex.  `min=0, max = 9`.. The range would be `10`..   `(9-0) + 1 = 10`, now multiple rand, range.  0 - 1, finally add the min as we might not be starting from 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that must be addressed is what *"an integer between 1 and 5"* means. Technically only 2, 3 and 4 are *between*, but you probably want 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5.

The function [Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) gives you a number between 0.0000000000000000 and 0.9999999999999998.

To get an integer from this value, for example between 20 and 30 you first must calculate the range: `range = max - min` . The range (in this case 30 - 20 = 10) is then multiplied with the result from Math.random, and the result is floored (rounded down) and the rounded result is 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 or 9. Notice that the number 10 is missing. After that the minimum value (20) is added, so the result is 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28 or 29.

If range = 10, and you multiply that with the largest value Math.random() can give you, you get 9.9999999999999998 and when you do Math.floor on it, it becomes 9. So with a range of 10, your could get 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9. Notice that you never can get the value 10.

It therefore depends on your definition of *"an integer between 20 and 30"*. Should it include the highest number (30) or not ?

If it should include the highest number, you need to add one to the range (like your code does). That is why the range is calculated as `(max - min + 1)`.

```js
function random(min, max) {
  let range = max - min + 1;
  return Math.floor( Math.random() * range ) + min
}

setInterval(
  function() { 
    let min = Math.min( input1.value, input2.value );
    let max = Math.max(  input1.value, input2.value );
    outputRange.value = max - min + 1;
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    li.textContent = random(min,max);
    output.insertBefore(li, output.firstChild);
    while (output.children.length > 10) {
      output.removeChild(output.lastChild);
    }
  },
  200
)
```

```css
label { display:block }
label span { display:inline-block; width:5em;}
label span, input, output { text-align:right; }
input, output { display:inline-block; width:5em; }
```

```html
<label><span>Min:</span><input id="input1" type="number" value="1"></label>
<label><span>Max:</span><input id="input2" type="number" value="10"></label>
<label><span>Range:</span><output id="outputRange"></output></label>
<ul id="output"></ul>
```

*Math.round (that rounds up or down to the nearest integer) could be used instead of Math.floor and that would eliminate the need to add one to the range. But, the people that will read your code in the future would not know if that was intentional or not. By using floor and by adding one to the range, it is crystal clear what you intended with your code, without writing a single comment.*

Comment: I'm happy that you have been helped, @Hacene.N . We have all been beginners at some point.